# iterate through two external file list and execute commands in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working to create a script that can take filelist1 (list of tar files) and filelist2 (list of directories).  I need to loop through / read these filelist and have the first file in filelist1 mv to first dir in filelist2.  Once there I will extract and perform other activities on the files in this folder.  Attempting to automate as I will have 130 plus tar files daily each containing between 75 and 200 hundred files that must be processed. Below is the script I am working on (WIP):

```
 #############################################################################
 #############################################################################
 #
 #  Incremental load script v1
 #  Created 02/09/2015 NHR
 #
 #############################################################################
 #############################################################################

 #
 # Clean up before running
 #
 # "/u02/hdfs_staging/ios/incremental/TOPACTR_DeltaFiles"
 #


 if [ -f filelist1 ]  ; then
    rm filelist1
 fi

 if [ -f filelist2 ] ; then
    rm filelist2
 fi

 #
 # Create filelist containing name of files parsed for dir's loaded from kdwxxxx
 #
 for i in *tar
     do
         echo "$i" | rev | cut -d"." -f2 | rev >> filelist1
     done

 #
 # Create work dir's for extracting tar files into for each date
 #
 while IFS= read -r file
     do
         [ ! -d "$file"  ] && mkdir "$file"
     done < "/u02/hdfs_staging/ios/incremental/TOPACTR_DeltaFiles/filelist1"

 #
 # Create filelist2 containing name of files parsed to copy
 # tar files to dir's for extraction
 #
 shopt -s nullglob                 # Bash extension, so that empty glob matches will work
   for file in ./*.tar ; do        # Use this, NOT "for file in *"
      echo  "$file" >> filelist2
   done

 #
 # Copy and Decompress tar files in these new dir's
 # HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO LOOP THROUGH THE FILELIST1 AND FILELIST2
 # AND PERFORM ADDITIONAL COMMANDS
 #



 #
 # Execute hive load to external table script to load incremental files to ios_incremental.
 # The ios_incremental database tables for these files is in place.
 #


 #hive -e CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE $filelist


 #
 # Run hive SQL script to add changed files to ios_staging tables.
 # This will be called from a hql script file and will require variables
 # for each table involved. This view combines record sets from both the
 # Base (base_table) and Change (incremental_table) tables and is reduced
 # only to the most recent records for each unique .id.  It is defined as
 # follows:
 #

 #hive -e
 # CREATE VIEW reconcile_view AS
 #    SELECT t1.* FROM
 #    (SELECT * FROM base_table
 #          UNION ALL
 #          SELECT * FROM incremental_table) t1
 #    JOIN
 #       (SELECT id, max(modified_date) max_modified FROM
 #           (SELECT * FROM base_table
 #           UNION ALL
 #           SELECT * FROM incremental_table) t2
 #       GROUP BY id) s
 #    ON t1.id = s.id AND t1.modified_date = s.max_modified;
 #


 #
 # Copy updated ios_staging data to update ios_prod db
 #



 #
 # Clean and Archive files to get ready for next incremental load
 #
```

Comment: So where is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to iterate through two lists simultaneously.

Here's one way of doing it, which assumes that the filenames don't have either a newline or a colon in their names (it's easy to change the colon to some other symbol):

```
paste -d: filelist1 filelist2 | while IFS=: read -r file1 file2; do
  some_command "$file1" "$file2"
  # ...
done
```

A more defensive solution would be to put the lists into arrays rather than files, and then iterate with a for loop. (I left out the creation of the arrays; there are lots of examples on SO):

```
for ((i=0;i<${#filearray1[@]};++i)); do
  file1="${filearray1[i]}"
  file2="${filearray2[i]}"
  some_command "$file1" "$file2"
  # ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (distinctly lacking in error checking):

```
exec 3< filelist1 4< filelist2

while read -u3 tarfile
do
  read -u4 destination
  mv "${tarfile}" "${destination}"/.
  ( cd "${destination}"
    # ... other stuff
  ) # subshell is to avoid having to cd back where you came from
done

exec 3<&- 4<&-
```